# Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, mvc

buen día!!

Anteriormente mi página funcionaba correctamente pero el día de ayer al hacer unas pruebas me empezó a marcar este error en el archivo select2.min.js lo cual se me hace raro porque no modifique nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando despliego un select es cuando me empieza a marcar el error mencionado pero si busco un estado en particular como se muestra no marca el error.

Con este código lleno el select

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="dropCN" style="display:none;">
            <h2>Selecciona el centro de negocios</h2>
            <div class="form-group form-group-default" style="width:400px;">
                <label class="">CN</label>
                <select id="select_cn" data-placeholder="Select Country" class="full-width" data-init-plugin="select2" style="width:350px;">
                    <!--onchange="SeleccionarCN(this.value);"-->
                    <optgroup label="TU CN ASIGNADO ACTUALMENTE">
                        <option value="@cn_pedido.SALESREP_ID">@cn_pedido.RESOURCE_NAME</option>
                    </optgroup>
                    @foreach (IGrouping<String, MiVianney.Models.CN> estados in ViewBag.Estados)
                    {
                        <optgroup label="@estados.Key">
                            @foreach (var cn in estados)
                            {
                                <option value="@cn.SALESREP_ID">@cn.RESOURCE_NAME</option>
                            }
                        </optgroup>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Y en el controller tengo esto

```
List<CN> lista_CN = ManejoDatos.wsObtenerCN(1);
            //LISTA CN 
            ViewBag.CN = lista_CN;
            //CN AGRUPADOS POR ESTADOS
            ViewBag.Estados = from estados in lista_CN group estados by estados.ESTADO;
```

Alguien sabe que pueda estar pasando?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Este error es mas bien de javascript que de c# no? Necesitaríamos ver el código que te lanza el error, pero básicamente estas usando `toUpperCase` en un objeto que es `undefined` o sea, que no está inicializado.

Comment: @Pikoh pero hasta este punto no uso javascript

Comment: Efectivamente el error es de Javascript. Le estas queriendo aplicar la funcion "toUpperCase" a un objeto no definido (undefined). y Como se ve ahi, se da en el archivo "select2.min.js"

Comment: El error es evidente que viene del código javascript del select. Pero el problema es posible que sea que la lista de elementos que le pasas exista algun elemento que sea nulo, y por eso da un error al intentar aplicar toupperstring a ese elemento. Yo revisaría la lista de elementos en busqueda de alguno que sea nulo

Comment: @Pikoh hay varios campos que vienen nulos pero de los nombres que es lo que ocupo mostrar no vienen nulos.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta remover los elementos nulos de la lista, como te sugieren en los comentarios, o bien intenta controlar esto reemplazando por `string`.

Por ahora, desde c#, lo unico que se me ocurre es que le apliques eso que te dije a la lista.

```
lista_CN.RemoveAll(item => item == null);
```

Answer (score 0):

quizá tienes una variable a la que le has agregado el .toUpperCase() que no tiene un valor... por ejemplo
this.variable.toUpperCase();
si esta no tiene un valor definido te botará error...

deberías validar:

si tiene valor: this.variable.toUpperCase();
si no tiene valor: this.variable